# iOS App Distribution : Can i upload iOS application with Homekit code + disable Homekit?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, itunes-store, homekit

We have created an application which contain HomeKit support. But still HomeKit support is not fully implemented. So we don't want to release that feature.

Will Apple check "HomeKit support" if we turn off HomeKit capability ?

The code will contain the code related to Homekit SDK but we have hide those screens related to HomeKit & disable the HomeKit Capability.

[image: Disable HomeKit capability from Xcode].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem uploading your app. But you should make sure that the code related to
`Home Kit SDK` does not affect any existing functionality you have in your app.
Apple only checks for Home Kit code if the capability for `Home Kit` is enabled in your Xcode.